# Is it possible to query the current user's Apple ID from the command line?

Tags: terminal, applescript, command-line, apple-id

Is it possible to query the current user's Apple ID from the command line? I want to create an AppleScript (run-only) app that will run only for a specific user (or at least for a user signed in with a specific AppleID), but I can't find any command (or third-party utility) that will do this.

Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The currently logged in Apple IDs for iCloud are stored in the MobileMeAccounts preferences. You can query the entire store with:

```
defaults read MobileMeAccounts Accounts
```

To return just the first account ID (an email address nowadays):

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print :Accounts:0:AccountID" ~/Library/Preferences/MobileMeAccounts.plist
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. One further question: is it possible that there will be more than one Account in the preferences, so that the second of the two commands will return a user who is not currently logged in?